# Using level to iterate working days

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying check the next 30 days, excluding weekends and holidays. So, for each working day, I have to return 24 hours (levl), starting now. I'm using the query below, but I don't know exactly what is the "connect by" clause.

```
select TO_char(t1.a_dt + ((level-1)/24),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') data_formatada,
       level levl
from (              
    SELECT  sysdate + LEVEL - 1 AS a_dt
    FROM    dual
    where   TO_CHAR (sysdate + LEVEL - 1, 'Dy' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ''ENGLISH''' )
                          NOT IN ('Sat', 'Sun')
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + TRUNC (sysdate + 30) - TRUNC (sysdate)
    MINUS
    select  HOLIDAY_DAY 
    from    HOLIDAYS ) t1
    connect by level <= 24 (??)
);
```

I'm expected the result like this:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Starting "right now", generate 720 rows, one hour apart, for 30 days * 24 hours, and then ignore (don't include) the rows where the date portion is a weekend or a holiday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dataformatada
FROM   (
  SELECT SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR' ) AS dataformatada
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  TRUNC( SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR' ) )
           - TRUNC( SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR' ), 'IW' ) < 5
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30*24
)
WHERE  TRUNC( dataformatada ) NOT IN ( SELECT HOLIDAY_DAY FROM HOLIDAYS );
```

Comment: Hi. 
Thanks a lot! I removed the subquery that return the holidays because the exception below:

ORA-32037: unsupported use of LEVEL in membership condition
So, I rewrite the query, using "minus":

select TO_char(t.data_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dte, rownum levl
from (
SELECT SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL(LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR') AS data_hora
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL(LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR')) - TRUNC(SYSDATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL( LEVEL - 1, 'HOUR' ), 'IW') < 5
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30*24
MINUS
SELECT HOLIDAY_DAY FROM HOLIDAYS) t;

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would be the case?

```
select TO_char(t1.a_dt + ((lvl- 1) / 24), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') data_formatada,
       lvl
  from (SELECT sysdate + LEVEL - 1 AS a_dt, level as lvl
          FROM dual
         where TO_CHAR(sysdate + LEVEL - 1,
                       'Dy',
                       'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ''ENGLISH''') NOT IN
               ('Sat', 'Sun')
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + TRUNC(sysdate + 30) - TRUNC(sysdate)
        MINUS
        select HOLIDAY_DAY, null lvl
          from HOLIDAYS) t1
```

Comment: Hi.
Unfortunelly, does not working:
ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block

Comment: I have edited the answer, forgot to change level into lvl

Answer (score 0):

A very simple (but somewhat inefficient) way to do this, if my "guess" in the Comment below your post is correct, would be something like this:

```
select     to_char(sysdate + (level - 1) / 24) as data_formatada
from       dual
where      to_char(sysdate + (level - 1) / 24, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language = English') 
              not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
  and      trunc(sysdate + (level - 1) / 24) not in ( select holiday_day from holidays )
connect by level <= 720
;
```